# How to Restrict Schema Access to Specific IP Address & user?

Tags: oracle-11g

I want to lock down access to specific schemas. Restrict the access to specific users when the connection is made from the specific  IP addresses.
Eg Only Access to USER1 and USER2

Comment: Oracle Version?

Comment: I m using Oracle 11g

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An AFTER LOGON trigger can be used for this purpose.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER system.check_ip_addresses 
AFTER LOGON 
ON DATABASE
BEGIN 
IF USER IN ('USER1', 'USER2') THEN
IF SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'IP_ADDRESS') NOT IN 
('192.168.0.10','192.168.0.11') THEN
  RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'Can not log in from this IP address (' || 
l_ip_address || ')');
END IF;
END IF;
END; 
 /
```

Remember the following points.

1. The trigger must use ON DATABASE, as making it schema specific would prevent the RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR from preventing the logon.
2. The trigger will fire for all connection attempts, so make sure you restrict which users it affects carefully to reduce the overhead.

Comment: Double for point 2; if you don't limit this to specific users, you could lock yourself out of the server. (Don't put the built in SYSTEM and SYS accounts in this trigger, in other words...)

Comment: Cam, That's a valuable point.  Have to take extra care while doing this.

Comment: That does not answer the question. It does not restrict access to specific schemas for these users. It simply does not allow these users to connect, That is a complete different thing.